# Calculus I Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$\int(\sqrt x + \sec x \tan x)\, dx$  using $u$-substitution.

So far as this class has been taught...  the class knows that in order to use $u$-substitution, a $u$ and its derivative must be present in the integral.  I cannot make sense of a $u$.  Help please.

Comment: $\frac d{dx}\sec x = \sec x \tan x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\int \sqrt{x}\:dx=\int x^{1/2}\:dx=\frac23x^{3/2}+C
$$ and
$$
\int \sec x \tan x\:dx=-\int \frac{-\sin x}{(\cos x)^2}\:dx=-\int \frac{(\cos x)'}{(\cos x)^2}\:dx=\frac1{\cos x}+C.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Split the integral into $\int \sqrt{x}\;dx + \int \sec(x)\tan(x)\,dx$ and solve each accordingly. A substitution you can use is $u=\tan(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is split the integral up into $\int\sqrt{x}dx+\int sec(x)tan(x)dx$ because this allows you to see the steps a bit more readily. The square root is a simple integral where you can use the power rule (I will leave this up to you).
Now let us consider *what* $sec(x)\cdot tan(x)$ is in more intuitive trig functions. We can look at this as $\frac{1}{cos(x)}\cdot \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}dx$. This makes our integral look like this: $\int \frac{sin(x)}{(cos(x))^2}dx$ which arguably has a more obvious u-substitution.

Hopefully this helps guide you in the right direction!